Salesforce Bulk API v2 Upsert showing in progress status
I am testing some CSV data records with special characters for an upsert operation and have set up Postman for this purpose. However, the job remains in the "in progress" state in Bulk Data Load Jobs. The authorised user has Field-Level Security (FLS) for the fields and access to the Object as well.
Here is the cURL command for generating the job ID and data ingestion that I used:
curl --location 'https://sbox_org_instance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/jobs/ingest' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data '{
"object": "Account",
"operation": "upsert",
"contentType": "CSV",
"externalIdFieldName": "AccountNumber__c"
}'
curl --location --request PUT 'https://sbox_org_instance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/jobs/ingest/job_id/batches/' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' 
--header 'Content-Type: text/csv' 
--data-raw '"RecordTypeId","Address__c","AccountNumber__c"
"0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXIAA","#123,@3rd Floor, Crystal Point Mall, !Link Road, Andheri West, Mumbai","4443"'
Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance for help!

Why are you using API version 49 instead of the latest (61)?
